# How to reset <iron-form> after dynamically loading data using <iron-ajax> in Polymer 2.x?

Tags: ajax, polymer, polymer-2.x, plunker, iron-elements

I want to reset my form buttons using the `reset()` method of the `<iron-form>`element.

#### Desired behavior

The desired behavior is that after clicking the <kbd>Reset</kbd> button, the two buttons that were originally `unchecked` to be `unchecked` and the two buttons that were originally `checked` to be `checked`.

#### Actual behavior

The actual behavior is that after clicking the <kbd>Reset</kbd> button, all the buttons flip to `unchecked`.

#### Demo

[Here is my Plunker demo.](https://plnkr.co/edit/viXDsAVrcmSOdAYriySm?p=preview) Note that in reality I am loading data from Firebase. In the demo, I am loading it from myjson.com.

#### Steps to recreate the problem

1. [Open this demo.](https://plnkr.co/edit/viXDsAVrcmSOdAYriySm?p=preview)
2. Notice two `checked` buttons and two `unchecked`.
3. Check the two `unchecked` buttons.
4. Click the <kbd>Reset</kbd> button.
5. Notice all the buttons flip to `unchecked`.

The desired behavior is for the two buttons that were originally `unchecked` to be `unchecked` and the two buttons that were originally `checked` to be `checked`.

#### Code

https://plnkr.co/edit/viXDsAVrcmSOdAYriySm?p=preview

```
<base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+v2.0.0/shadycss+webcomponents+1.0.0/components/">
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="paper-toggle-button/paper-toggle-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="iron-form/iron-form.html">
<link rel="import" href="iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
<link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">


<dom-module id="my-demo">
  <template>
    <style>
      paper-button, form > * {
        margin-top: 40px;
        font-size: 18px;
      }
    </style>

    <iron-ajax
      id="ajax"
      auto
      url="https://api.myjson.com/bins/1dntup"
      last-response="{{item}}"
      handle-as="json"
      >
    </iron-ajax>

    <iron-form id="form">
      <form>
        <paper-toggle-button name="alice" checked="{{item.alice}}">Alice</paper-toggle-button>
        <paper-toggle-button name="bob" checked="{{item.bob}}">Bob</paper-toggle-button>
        <paper-toggle-button name="charlie" checked="{{item.charlie}}">Charlie</paper-toggle-button>
        <paper-toggle-button name="dave" checked="{{item.dave}}">Dave</paper-toggle-button>
      </form>
    </iron-form>

    <paper-button on-tap="_onTap">Reset</paper-button>

  </template>

  <script>
    class MyDemo extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() {
        return 'my-demo';
      }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          item: {
            type: Object,
            notify: true,
          },
        };
      }

      ready() {
        super.ready();
      }

      _onTap() {
        this.$.form.reset();
        }

    }

    window.customElements.define(MyDemo.is, MyDemo);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

#### Edits

User @madietov of the [Polymer Slack Site](https://polymer.slack.com) points out that [the source code here](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-form/blob/master/iron-form.html#L181) uses a protected method called `_init()` to initialize the default settings. And this `_init()` method seems to be called before the `<iron-ajax>` element returns its values.

`_init()` sets a protected property called `_defaults`. If I could access either the protected method or protected property, then I could call the method or set the property after `<iron-ajax>` returns its initial values.

Comment: Why don't you just do another iron-ajax after reset and get the default values again?
_onTap() {
        this.$.form.reset();
        this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
     }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
this.$.form.reset();
```

with

```
this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/4ROGJbzqk98X6FtbVSCN?p=preview)

https://plnkr.co/edit/4ROGJbzqk98X6FtbVSCN?p=preview

```
<base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+v2.0.0/shadycss+webcomponents+1.0.0/components/">
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="paper-toggle-button/paper-toggle-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="iron-form/iron-form.html">
<link rel="import" href="iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
<link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">


<dom-module id="my-demo">
  <template>
    <style>
      paper-button, form > * {
        margin-top: 40px;
        font-size: 18px;
      }
    </style>

    <iron-ajax
      id="ajax"
      auto
      url="https://api.myjson.com/bins/1dntup"
      last-response="{{item}}"
      handle-as="json"
      >
    </iron-ajax>

    <iron-form id="form">
      <form>
        <paper-toggle-button name="alice" checked="{{item.alice}}">Alice</paper-toggle-button>
        <paper-toggle-button name="bob" checked="{{item.bob}}">Bob</paper-toggle-button>
        <paper-toggle-button name="charlie" checked="{{item.charlie}}">Charlie</paper-toggle-button>
        <paper-toggle-button name="dave" checked="{{item.dave}}">Dave</paper-toggle-button>
      </form>
    </iron-form>

    <paper-button on-tap="_onTap">Reset</paper-button>

  </template>

  <script>
    class MyDemo extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() {
        return 'my-demo';
      }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          item: {
            type: Object,
            notify: true,
          },
        };
      }

      ready() {
        super.ready();
      }

      _onTap() {
        //this.$.form.reset();
        this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
        }

    }

    window.customElements.define(MyDemo.is, MyDemo);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Credit

Summary from comments.
Hat tip: @AneesHameed